# (Python) Create New Column Based on Values of Existing Column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset of 116 rows and 43 columns.  I would like to create a new column from an existing column in my Python dataset.

This column would be a modification of a "Location" column that already exists in my data.  There are 7 unique locations and I want to combine 3 of the locations based on the condition that they appear <4 times in my dataset.

Let's say we have Locations: A, B, C, D, E, F, and G.  The locations have the following number of occurrences in my dataset.

```
Location     NumRows
A            41
B            30
C            28
D            8
E            3
F            3
G            2
```

According to what I described above, I would like a new column (Location 2) to have the following number of rows:

```
Location     NumRows
A            41
B            30
C            28
D            8
Other        8
```

Can someone help me with the syntax in creating this new column?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I’m guessing this is a Pandas DataFrame? Have you read the Pandas docs?

Comment: Also, I believe the example you've given does not accurately convey/represent the conditions you gave, namely _There are 7 unique locations and I want to combine 3 of the locations based on the condition that they appear <4 times in my dataset._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a column of locations:

```
print(df)                                                               
   ID Location
0   1        A
1   2        B
2   3        A
3   4        C
4   5        E
5   6        F
6   7        G
7   8        D
8   9        D
9  10        B
```

You could use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df['NewLocation'] = df['Location']
df.loc[df['NewLocation'].isin(['E','F','G']), 'NewLocation'] = 'Other'
```

---

```
print(df)                                                              
   ID Location NewLocation
0   1        A           A
1   2        B           B
2   3        A           A
3   4        C           C
4   5        E       Other
5   6        F       Other
6   7        G       Other
7   8        D           D
8   9        D           D
9  10        B           B
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do:

```
locs = ['E','F','G']

# calculate value
v = df.query("Location in @locs")['NumRows'].sum()

# create a new row
r = pd.Series(['Other', v], index=['Location','NumRows'])

# append the new row in data
df = df.query("Location not in @locs").append(r, ignore_index=True)

  Location  NumRows
0        A       41
1        B       30
2        C       28
3        D        8
4    Other        8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `.groupby()` and `np.where()`:

```
df = df.groupby(
        np.where(df['Location'].isin(['E', 'F', 'G']), 'Other', df.Location)
    ).sum().reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Location'})
```

---

```
  Location  NumRows
0        A       41
1        B       30
2        C       28
3        D        8
4    Other        8
```